# Showing specific table results - Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table

I have a table which I populate with JSON data. Since there's more than 3000 records, I wanted to have a show more and show less button that don't mess up my search functions. Here is the code I use to populate my table

```
<table id="data1"></table>

$.getJSON("http://127.0.0.1:8000/steamcrawler.json",
function (data1) {  
document.getElementById("data1").innerHTML;
var tr;
for (var i = 0; i < data1[i].length; i++) {
    tr = $('<tr/>');
    tr.append("<td>" + data1[i].name + "</td>");
    tr.append("<td>" + data1[i].discount_price + "</td>");
    $('#data1').append(tr);
}
});
```

There's a few conditions I have to meet that are making showing only 10 or 20 results very tricky.

1) I have a search bar, so if the style is set to display: none for certain rows, the hidden results don't appear when the user types a name in.

2) Since there are so many records I can't overcome the problem above by just adding an onclick change display to block for all records function to the searchbar.

2) I have this code for showing more rows, but don't know how to modify my append function above. I get that slice (0, 10) does the same as if i'd set [i] to be less than 10 in my for loop, is it possible to merge the two pieces of code somehow?

```
var trs = $("#data1 tr");
var currentIndex = 10;

trs.hide();
trs.slice(0, 10).show();

function btnMore(e) { 
  e.preventDefault();
  $("#data1 tr").slice(currentIndex, currentIndex + 10).show();
  currentIndex += 10;
};
```

Thank you. I'm quite inexperienced with Javascript so any alternate methods of doing this are equally welcome.

Comment: Look at some existing libraries / jQuery plugins. For example https://www.datatables.net/